# Enter a code, click on a label and then on a button with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am interested in entering a code in a search bar, clicking on a label and finally clicking on a button. Specifically, the page is https://www.icribis.com/it/. I have to enter the code in the search bar (where the message "Inserisci i dati dell'azienda" appears), then I have to click on the label "Codice fiscale" (under the search bar) and finally click on the button with the magnifying glass. My attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

url = 'https://www.icribis.com/it/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

# Disable cookies
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uc-center-container > div:nth-child(2) div > button:nth-child(3)")').click()

# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'clearfix')]//input[@name='search']"))).send_keys("my_code")

# Click on the label
# ...

# Click on the button with the magnifying glass
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'media-obj-right')]//input[@type='submit']"))).click()
```

How can I click on a label? And the other two lines are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'clearfix')]//input[@name='search']
```

does not have any match, you should use this id:

```
companySearchFormInput
```

or **XPath**:

```
//input[@id='companySearchFormInput']
```

**Code:**

```
# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "companySearchFormInput"))).send_keys("my_code")
```

or

```
# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='companySearchFormInput']"))).send_keys("my_code")
```

**Update1 with **ID**, **CSS_SELECTOR**:**

```
time.sleep(5)

# Disable cookies
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uc-center-container > div:nth-child(2) div > button:nth-child(3)")').click()

# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "companySearchFormInput"))).send_keys("my_code")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='search-type-fiscal-code']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Cerca']"))).click()
```

**Update2 with **Xpath**:**

If you want to have only **XPath based solution:**

```
time.sleep(5)

# Disable cookies
driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uc-center-container > div:nth-child(2) div > button:nth-child(3)")').click()

# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='companySearchFormInput']"))).send_keys("my_code")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='search-type-fiscal-code']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Cerca']"))).click()
```

Comment: Yes, now it works. How about clicking on the label "Codice fiscale"?

Comment: Please see the updated code above

Comment: See updated 2 if you want to have only XPath based locators.

Comment: @LJG in order to click on "Codice fiscale" you can use this XPath locator: `//input[@id='search-type-fiscal-code']`

Answer (score 1):

instead of this XPath locator

```py
//div[contains(@class,'clearfix')]//input[@name='search']
```

You can use this

```py
//input[@name='search']
```

Also this XPath is not unique

```py
//div[contains(@class,'media-obj-right')]//input[@type='submit']
```

Try using

```py
//div[@id='companySearch']//input[@type='submit']
```

Instead
So your code could be:

```py
# Enter the code
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='search']"))).send_keys("my_code")
# Click on the button with the magnifying glass
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='companySearch']//input[@type='submit']"))).click()
```